# не могу удалить индекс mysql

Tags: php, mysql

здравствуйте, не могу удалить индекс столбца из бд

пробовал добавить его заного и удалять - удаляется, но иконка серого ключика не пропадает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а если так `ALTER TABLE users DROP INDEX user;`

Comment: к сожалению не помогает

Comment: `user` а такой индекс существует в вашей таблице? Как я вижу `user` - назва колонки, но не индекса!

Comment: как видите возле колонки users иконка серого ключа, и title у него = "Индекс"

Comment: А что дает команда "show indexes in users" ?

Comment: https://pp.vk.me/c637426/v637426213/2f37a/h5WRyI6eW3s.jpg

Answer (score -1):

В PHPMyAdmin слева, где указаны все таблицы, есть плюсик. Его раскрываешь, там есть поле «Индексы». Оттуда удалить попробуй.

Comment: там нету этого поля

Comment: https://vk.com/doc245028753_441617067
Выбираешь структуру таблицы. Внизу под таблицей есть вкладка индексы. Раскрываешь ее, видишь все индексы на таблицу. Для удаления достаточно нажать крестик.